# XMLParseErrorException when calling a webservice from android application

Tags: android, web-services, jboss

I've a simple java project containing a simple webservice

**Package**: pcp.webservices

**File WEB-INF/lib/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Pcp web services</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>pcpWS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pcp.webservices.pcpWS</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pcpWS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pcpWS</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

File **src/pcpWS.java**:

```
@WebService(name = "pcpWS")
/** @SOAPBinding indica información vinculate para los mensajes SOAP.*/
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,  
use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,  
parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)

public class pcpWS {

    @WebMethod
// Usuario is an external class containing filed likes Name,Surname,...
    public Usuario ValidarUsuario(@WebParam(name = "login") String login,@WebParam(name = "password") String password) {
        //comprobar si existe o no el usuario

        //codigo de prueba
        Usuario u=new Usuario();
        if (login.contentEquals("H"))
        {
            u.IdUsuario = "8888";
            u.Nombre = "Andrea";
            u.Apellidos = "Martín";
            u.Rol = "Administrador";
            u.Centro = "Keyland Valladolid";
        }
        else
        {
            u.IdUsuario = "9999";
            u.Nombre = "Pablo";
            u.Apellidos = "Díaz";
            u.Rol = "Trabajador";
            u.Centro = "Keyland Valladolid";
        }

        return u;
    }

}
```

The webservice is deployed JBoss 4.2 and the following **wsdl file** is generated:

```
<definitions name='pcpWSService' targetNamespace='http://webservices.pcp/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:tns='http://webservices.pcp/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
 <types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace='http://webservices.pcp/' version='1.0' xmlns:tns='http://webservices.pcp/' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
   <xs:element name='ConsultarNotificaciones' type='tns:ConsultarNotificaciones'/>
   <xs:element name='ConsultarNotificacionesResponse' type='tns:ConsultarNotificacionesResponse'/>
   <xs:element name='Responsables' type='tns:Responsables'/>
   <xs:element name='ResponsablesResponse' type='tns:ResponsablesResponse'/>
   <xs:element name='ValidarUsuario' type='tns:ValidarUsuario'/>
   <xs:element name='ValidarUsuarioResponse' type='tns:ValidarUsuarioResponse'/>
   <xs:complexType name='ValidarUsuario'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='login' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='password' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='ValidarUsuarioResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='return' type='tns:usuario'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='usuario'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='IdUsuario' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Nombre' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Apellidos' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Rol' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Centro' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='apellidos' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='centro' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='idUsuario' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='nombre' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='rol' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='Responsables'>
    <xs:sequence/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='ResponsablesResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element maxOccurs='unbounded' minOccurs='0' name='return' type='tns:responsable'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='responsable'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Id' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Nombre' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='nombre' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='ConsultarNotificaciones'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='idUsu' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='ConsultarNotificacionesResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element maxOccurs='unbounded' minOccurs='0' name='return' type='tns:notificacion'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='notificacion'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Descripcion' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Fecha' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='Tipo' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='URL' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </types>
 <message name='pcpWS_Responsables'>
  <part element='tns:Responsables' name='Responsables'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='pcpWS_ValidarUsuarioResponse'>
  <part element='tns:ValidarUsuarioResponse' name='ValidarUsuarioResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='pcpWS_ResponsablesResponse'>
  <part element='tns:ResponsablesResponse' name='ResponsablesResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='pcpWS_ConsultarNotificaciones'>
  <part element='tns:ConsultarNotificaciones' name='ConsultarNotificaciones'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='pcpWS_ConsultarNotificacionesResponse'>
  <part element='tns:ConsultarNotificacionesResponse' name='ConsultarNotificacionesResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='pcpWS_ValidarUsuario'>
  <part element='tns:ValidarUsuario' name='ValidarUsuario'></part>
 </message>
 <portType name='pcpWS'>
  <operation name='ConsultarNotificaciones' parameterOrder='ConsultarNotificaciones'>
   <input message='tns:pcpWS_ConsultarNotificaciones'></input>
   <output message='tns:pcpWS_ConsultarNotificacionesResponse'></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name='Responsables' parameterOrder='Responsables'>
   <input message='tns:pcpWS_Responsables'></input>
   <output message='tns:pcpWS_ResponsablesResponse'></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name='ValidarUsuario' parameterOrder='ValidarUsuario'>
   <input message='tns:pcpWS_ValidarUsuario'></input>
   <output message='tns:pcpWS_ValidarUsuarioResponse'></output>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding name='pcpWSBinding' type='tns:pcpWS'>
  <soap:binding style='document' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
  <operation name='ConsultarNotificaciones'>
   <soap:operation soapAction=''/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name='Responsables'>
   <soap:operation soapAction=''/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name='ValidarUsuario'>
   <soap:operation soapAction=''/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name='pcpWSService'>
  <port binding='tns:pcpWSBinding' name='pcpWSPort'>
   <soap:address location='http://127.0.0.1:8080/webServices/pcpWS'/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

**Calling code (from android application):**

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://webservices.pcp/";
private final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1";
private final String SOAPACTION = "";
private final String METHOD = "ValidarUsuario";

                 String user = pars[0];
                 String password = pars[1];
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD); 
                SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                sobre.dotNet = false;       
                request.addProperty("login", user);        
                request.addProperty("password", password); 
                sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);        
                try {
                    transporte.call(SOAPACTION, sobre);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                //  JOptionPane.e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SoapObject resultado = null;
                try {
                    resultado = (SoapObject)sobre.getResponse();
                } catch (SoapFault e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //comprobar si devuelve un usuario nulo o no

                Usuario usu = new Usuario();
                usu.IdUsuario= resultado.getProperty(0).toString();
                usu.Nombre = resultado.getProperty(1).toString();
                usu.Apellidos = resultado.getProperty(2).toString();
                usu.Rol = resultado.getProperty(3).toString();   
                usu.Centro=resultado.getProperty(4).toString();
```

The exception launched is **XmlPullParserException** and indeed the variable **resultado** after catching the exception is still null.

It seems the webservice is called correctly but an exception is launched.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the complete **logcat stack trace**:

```
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.es/es.es.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.es/es.es.MiCuentaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.es/es.es.MiCuentaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at es.es.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)

06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 11 more
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at es.es.MiCuentaActivity.onCreate(MiCuentaActivity.java:25)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-18 11:49:21.964: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 19 more
```

(MainActivity is the "base" activity in the application, the code is run within a AsynkThread because if done in main thread,AccesoCuentaActivity,it launchas `NetworkOnMainThreadException`)

Comment: You should probably include the complete stack-trace from logcat.

Comment: just edited adding stack trace

Comment: So, what are you doing here, `MiCuentaActivity.java, line 25`, that is causing the `NullPointerException` that in turn is crashing your app?

Comment: The fact is that I pass the object "usu" to MainActivity and ManActivity launch MiCuentaActivity but of course if "usu" is null (and should not be null) it gives problems

Comment: Well, in that case, attach the stack-trace for the XmlPullParserException instead, you should have that in your logcat as well according to the code snippets you pasted into your question.

Comment: Finally I solved. It was a bug of JBoss (missing libraries)